# Ошибка монтирования каталога Docker на Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10

[image: АШЫБКА!!!]

> PS C:\Users\Rosso\Documents\GitHub\mlcourse_open> docker run -it  --rm -p 5022:22 -p 4545:4545 -v C:\Users\Rosso\Documents\GitHub\mlcourse_open\ -w /notebooks festline/mlcourse_open jupyter
>
> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid volume spec "C:\Users\Rosso\Documents\GitHub\mlcourse_open\": invalid volume specification
>   : 'C:\Users\Rosso\Documents\GitHub\mlcourse_open\': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: '\Users\Rosso\Documents\GitHub\mlcourse_open\' mount path must be absolute.
>   See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

При использовании предложенного варианта возникает аналогичная ошибка. 
Диск C в настройках докера примонтировал.
Как правильно примонтировать каталог для контейнера?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow! Пожалуйста, отредактируйте ваше сообщение, вписав туда _текст_ ошибки, не используйте снимки экрана для этого - ничего не видно же.

Comment: У меня картиночка прекрасно разворачивается, но да, ок, сделал